# Setting minimum and maximum value for kivy integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.6

I have a number that i want to range from 0 to 100, no more and no less. I tried setting the number as:

```
ego = NumericProperty(0, min=0, max=100)
```

However, the number still allows itself to go over 100 when I press this button:

```
on_release: root.update_ego()
Button:
    text: "increase ego"
    pos: 700,500
    on_release: root.update_ego()
```

And my .py file says this:

```
def update_ego(self):
    self.ego += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
from kivy.properties import BoundedNumericProperty
...
# returns the boundary value when exceeded
ego = BoundedNumericProperty(0, min=0, max=100,
    errorhandler=lambda x: 100 if x > 100 else 0)
```

## Example - Float Point Decimal

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BoundedNumericProperty


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    ego = BoundedNumericProperty(0.0, min=0.0, max=2.0,
                                 errorhandler=lambda x: 2.0 if x > 2.0 else 0.0)

    def update_ego(self):
        print('before increment: ego={0:5.2f}'.format(self.ego))
        self.ego += 1.0
        print('after increment: ego={0:5.2f}'.format(self.ego))


class Test2App(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test2App().run()
```

### test2.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "{0:5.2f}".format(root.ego)
    Button:
        text: "increase ego"
        on_release: root.update_ego()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Does it also work for decimals? (e.g how would i make a variable that ranges from 0 to 20 and can only have 1 decimal place?)

Comment: Yes, it also works for floating point decimal. Please refer to my example for details.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the cause of the problem from this (maybe you have to set the number at another place in the code), I suggest this workaround:

```
def update_ego(self):
    if self.ego < 100:
        self.ego += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, for others that drunkenly stumble in here, you can totally update variables in the kivy button itself.

```
Button:
    text: "increase ego"
    on_release: root.ego = root.ego + 1
```

This can cut down the number of functions you have, and save you from unneeded logic hurdles.